# Generic function to get item of any std::vector containing in a given class by index

Tags: c++

If I have a class containing only `std::vector` of any type as data member and I would like to make a generic function allowing me to retrieve elements by index in any vector.

What can I do to create such a function. I tried to do it using pointers to my getters and it worked but I don't know if it is really a good solution.

Is there an example of such class

```
class S
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> someIntegers;
        std::vector<double> someDoubles;
        std::vector<double> someDoubles2;
        std::vector<int> someIntergers2;
        std::vector<B> someBs;
       public:
               const std::vector<int>& getSomeIntegers1() const { return someIntergers; }
               // and so on ...

}
```

My solution is to do that:

```
   template<typename T>
   std::optional<T> getByIndex(const S& s, const std::vector<T>& (S::*getCnt)() const , size_t index = 0)
   {
       if (const auto& cnt = (s.*getCnt)();
           index >= 0 && index < cnt.size())
           return cnt.at(index);
           return {};
   }
```

I'm not sure if it's a great solution due to the lack of readability.

Comment: Could you show an example of how such access would be used? Why do you want a single template function, instead of separate accessors for each vector?

Comment: How would you like it to work? I think this function works; you would write it as `getByIndex(s, &S::getSomeIntegers1, 42)` but I wonder why you do not simply prefer to write `getByIndex(s.getSomeIntegers1(), 24)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Here i just put a simple case but in my real case the function getByIndex don't take a S parameter but another class with which we will compute an instance of S.

Comment: Why even bother using a wrapper function at all? `s.getSomeIntegers1()[24]` would work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a generic access that routes to individual members based on the template parameter, you must define the mapping manually. However, using the template argument as selector will not support cases with multiple member vectors of the same type, for example the `someDoubles` and `someDoubles2`.

Here is a sample code to retrieve the correct vector

```
template <class T>
std::vector<T>& getContainer();

template <>
std::vector<int>& getContainer() {
    return someIntegers;
}
template <>
std::vector<double>& getContainer() {
    return someDoubles;
}
// Do so for every type you want to support
```